# How to set identity value properly in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Replicate database A to database B. All the needed tables are replicated now I stop the replication. TBL_state has 25 records, but when I check the current identity value it shows null

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TBL_State', NORESEED)
```

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value '25'.
> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

When I try to reseed the identity value it gives the following response, how to set identity value properly.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TBL_State', RESEED, 25);
```

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL'.
> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Comment: The message given after RESEED command gives the value of the identity column before RESEED.  Try DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TBL_State'). The resulting message will give the "current" value and also "column" value.

Comment: What's the value returned by `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TBL_State')` ?

Comment: Is the table empty, can you do select COUNT(*) from TBL_State?